# Группировка по метке

Tags: python, pandas

Имеются данные, нужно разбить на 9 интервалов. Проблема заключается в том, что нужно проверить какому интервалу принадлежат данные (К примеру если первому интервалу  то обозначаем А1 если второму то А2 и так далее). а после создать массив пар по первому номеру (к примеруА1-А2, А1-А3, А1-6)
[image: данные и к каким Аi принадлежат]

[image: Аi в зависимости от интервала]
[image: массив пар по первому номеру]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('example.xlsx')

require_cols = [1]
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', usecols=require_cols)
df_min_max = df.aggregate(['min', 'max'])

my_list = df["Data"].tolist()
interval = pd.cut(np.array(my_list), 9)
print(my_list)
print(interval)
print(df_min_max)
```

Моя попытка реализации

*3414, 3563, 3391, 3463, 3110, 2844, 3292, 3321, 3608, 2753, 2886, 3596, 3644, 4029, 4023, 4870, 5859, 6321, 5923, 5699, 5521, 5995*
исходные данные

Comment: Врядли кто-то захочет вбивать ваши данные с картинок для того чтобы помочь вам... Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: сейчас прикреплю данные, фото я привел для наглядного примера, как должно получится

Comment: *3414, 3563, 3391, 3463, 3110, 2844, 3292, 3321, 3608, 2753, 2886, 3596, 3644, 4029, 4023, 4870, 5859, 6321, 5923, 5699, 5521, 5995* это исходные данные

Comment: все данные в вопрос пожалуйста - под вопросом есть кнопка "править". Кроме того стоит пояснить алгоритм действий на третьей картинке - пока ничего непонятно

Comment: на третей карртинке, я смотрю на первую картинку, и смотрю откуда куда Аi уходит (например, первые данные А2 а вторые А3 значит получаем А2-А3 это относим ко второй группе)

Comment: и смотрю сколь выходит из А2 потом смотрю сколько выходит из А3 и так далее

Comment: ничего не понял... ну да ладно, может другие поймут и не поленятся вбить данные для столбца `Ai` ручками - у меня на это нет времени) Удачи вам!

Comment: Вы читали ответ по ссылке из первого комментария?

Comment: Хорошо, попробую так: Имеются данные, нужно разбить на 9 интервалов. После проверить каждый элемент к какому интервалу он принадлежит